# Location of TFBS in genome

Tags: transcription, snp, binding-sites

I have an annotated set of SNPs and I would like to explore the difference in the binding affinity of the transcription factor (TF) if I have a SNP in my locus. As my SNPs are annotated (I know wether it is in an intron variant, downstream gene variant, missions variant, etc...) I might explore the binding affinity of those SNPs that are categorized as intron variant, downstream variant,upstream_gene_variant, non_coding_transcript_variant, 5_prime_UTR_variant and not take into consideration SNPs that are "missense variants". The reason why I want to do so is that transcription factor binding sites (TFBS) might be located before gene and after it.

What do you think about it? Can a TFBS be located in the exon of a gene? What are the locations of the TFBS regarding the exons,introns, 5' UTR etc?

Comment: Lots of annotated SNPs are located nowhere near  any part of any gene, so you would be quite fortunate to (a) find a SNP that maps close to a gene of interest. It would be even rarer for a public SNP to map in top of a relevant TFBS. If you had some SNPs from an unpublished study that might be cool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would link your data with the [ENCODE](https://www.encodeproject.org/) dataset. This dataset provides locations of TFBS. It is also accessible via the [UCSC genome browser](https://genome.ucsc.edu/).

For the actual question TFBS are located pretty much everywhere, including exons (as described [here](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/342/6164/1325.summary)), introns and of course intergenic regions (e.g. enhancers, silencers, control locus regions - [here](http://www.annualreviews.org/doi/abs/10.1146/annurev.genom.7.080505.115623?url_ver=Z39.88-2003&rfr_dat=cr_pub%3Dpubmed&rfr_id=ori%3Arid%3Acrossref.org&journalCode=genom) a reference).

Comment: what about the binding affinities? Is there any tool where I can insert my notrmal sequence and a sequence with snp and it will predict the difference? I know sTRAP(http://trap.molgen.mpg.de) is suitable for that, however the online results differ from r-version results

Comment: @Tonja This [page](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Transcription_factor_binding_site_prediction2) contains some suitable software. If you know what TF you are looking at, you might want to look at this [page](http://seqanswers.com/forums/showthread.php?t=27484).